# How do I mock a method of a mocked module with Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, electron

I am trying to mock the 'dialog' in electron module using jest and running into issues below.
When setting up the mock directly on the object it is working(case 1). However when storing the mock function in a variable and setting that in the mock object fails(case 2). Any input why this is the case? I am new to jest and js in general. However I thought these two cases should behave the same.

Case 1: Working

```
jest.mock('electron', () => ({
  dialog: {
    showOpenDialog: jest.fn(()=>({filePaths:['']})),
  },
}));
```

Case 2: Not working. Error: TypeError: electron_1.dialog.showOpenDialog is not a function

```
const showOpenDialogMock = jest.fn(()=>({filePaths:['']}));
jest.mock('electron', () => ({
  dialog: {
    showOpenDialog: showOpenDialogMock,
  },
}));
```

Test:

```
test("Menu click", async () => {   

    const setDirMenuItem = subMenu.getSetProjectDirSubMenu(
      <any>mainWindow,
      <any>projectSettings
    );
    await setDirMenuItem.click();
    expect(showOpenDialogMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }
  );
```

Code in test:

```
export const getSetProjectDirSubMenu = (
  mainWindow: BrowserWindow,
  projectSettings: ProjectSettings
) => ({
  label: 'Set Project Directory',
  click: async () => {
    const result = await dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
      properties: ['openDirectory'],
      defaultPath: projectSettings.getProjectDir()
    });

    if (result.filePaths[0]) {
      projectSettings.setProjectDir(result.filePaths[0]);
      mainWindow.webContents.send('PROJECT_DIRECTORY_SET', {});
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jest.mock` calls are moved to the top of the file (hoisted). So in Case 2, the mock is created before `const showOpenDialogMock` is defined.

The code that actually runs looks more like:

```js
jest.mock('electron', () => ({
  dialog: {
    showOpenDialog: showOpenDialogMock,
  },
}));
const showOpenDialogMock = jest.fn(()=>({filePaths:['']}));
```

Knowing that, here's what you might try instead:

```js
import {dialog} from 'electron';

jest.mock('electron', () => ({
  dialog: {
    showOpenDialog: jest.fn(()=>({filePaths:['']})),
  },
}));

test("Menu click", async () => {   
  const setDirMenuItem = subMenu.getSetProjectDirSubMenu(
    <any>mainWindow,
    <any>projectSettings
  );
  await setDirMenuItem.click();
  // note: dialog.showOpenDialog
  expect(dialog.showOpenDialog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

[More on module functions and mocking modules from Jest documentation.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules)